# Error creating bean with name Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm writing a project in java and tomcat(9.0.8) in intellj idea 2018.1. when I use jdk1.8, everything is just fine, however in jdk10 this error comes out. I don't know what is wrong with jdk10.

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'proviceMasterController': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: protected javax.validation.Validator
> com.jeeplus.common.web.BaseController.validator; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
> [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
> at
> com.jeeplus.modules.sys.listener.WebContextListener.initWebApplicationContext(WebContextListener.java:16)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4627)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5091)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: protected javax.validation.Validator
> com.jeeplus.common.web.BaseController.validator; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
> [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
> ... 59 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
> [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
> ... 61 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374) at
> org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2252) at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227) at
> org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214) at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.(Version.java:27) at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:66)
> at
> org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
> at
> javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
> ... 71 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
> ... 85 more 2018-07-13 23:45:33,830 DEBUG
> [com.jeeplus.common.utils.SpringContextHolder] -
> 清除SpringContextHolder中的ApplicationContext:Root WebApplicationContext:
> startup date [Fri Jul 13 23:45:25 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
> 2018-07-13 23:45:33,866 ERROR
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context
> initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'proviceMasterController': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: protected javax.validation.Validator
> com.jeeplus.common.web.BaseController.validator; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
> [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
> at
> com.jeeplus.modules.sys.listener.WebContextListener.initWebApplicationContext(WebContextListener.java:16)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4627)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5091)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
> at
> java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
> at
> java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
> at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method) at
> java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: protected javax.validation.Validator
> com.jeeplus.common.web.BaseController.validator; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
> [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
 ... 59 more Caused by:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'validator' defined in file
 [/Users/laiyinan/Documents/后台开发/SaveBearAdmin/out/artifacts/savebear_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring-context.xml]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
 at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
 ... 61 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at
 java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 13-Jul-2018
 23:45:33.868 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
 listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
 appropriate container log file at
 java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374) at
 org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2252) 13-Jul-2018
 23:45:33.869 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
 startup failed due to previous errors at
 java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227) at
 org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214) at
 org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.(Version.java:27) at
 org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:66)
 at
 org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
 at
 javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
> ... 71 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
> ... 85 more
```

Comment: JAXB is no longer part of the JRE - add a dependency.

Comment: how? i dont know how to add a dependency.